# Article Extraction - Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boilerpipe

Is there any option to extract only the content from a webpage using ruby. (Avoid links and other stuffs)

Answer (score 2):

To do web scraping you should use gem `mechanize` with `nokogiri` for dom parsing.

Comment: I had used mechanize to scrap, but boilerpipe library works better to extract only article-content of the web page in python.  I want to know whether there is a gem similar to boilerpipe.

Comment: `Mechanize` is fastest library for the job and `nokogiri` will allow you to just scrape the parts of the page that you want. (the article)

Comment: Is it possible to scrap the content from different websites without passing css or html tags using mechanize and nokogiri????

Comment: You cant scrape with any tool without parsing the dom. You need to tell it what you want to scrape.

Comment: No I don't share my personal contact information. If you want help post your questions here and someone will reply. I need to go soon so if you want to share the URL I can get you started with the XPATH

Comment: This is the one http://tomazkovacic.com/blog/14/extracting-article-text-from-html-documents/.
I require only the content from overview to conclusion not any other stuff...

Comment: Ok everything that you want can be scraped using this XPATH `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "entry-title", " " ))] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "entry-content", " " ))]` I'm going to bed now. Good luck.

Comment: I've ported Boilerpipe to a pure ruby implementation https://rubygems.org/gems/boilerpipe-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It's Python, not Ruby but it's awesome what you can do with very little effort.

Comment: Thank you, i will go through Scrapy.